# Optional injection in Guice

Tags: java, guice

Is it possible to tell Guice that it's not necessary to inject all constructor arguments? For example, I have a constructor `Foo` that takes two args of types `Bar` and `Baz`. All of them are optional in my system: they may

1. both present
2. both missing
3. only `Bar` present
4. only `Baz` present.

That said, it depends on other modules providing these bindings. I want to get something like this:

```
class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;
  private final Baz baz;

  @Inject(optional = true)
  public Foo(@Nullable Bar bar, @Nullable Baz baz) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz;
  }
}
```

But I can't really use `optional` with constructors. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What would the default value be? Conventionally, optional dependencies are expressed using setters instead of constructor arguments.

Comment: A default null is fine for me. So I should make the constructor empty and use setters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the [preferred Guice pattern](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-can-i-inject-optional-parameters-into-a-constructor) for this is:

```java
public class HolderPatter {

  static class Bar {
    @Inject Bar(BarDependency dependency) {}
  }
  static class Baz {
    @Inject Baz(BazDependency dependency) {}
  }

  static class BarHolder {
    @Inject(optional=true) Bar value = null;
  }

  static class BazHolder {
    @Inject(optional=true) Baz value = null;
  }

  static class Foo {
    private final Bar bar;
    private final Baz baz;

    @Inject
    public Foo(BarHolder bar, BazHolder baz) {
      this.bar = bar.value;
      this.baz = baz.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this will also allow you to specify sane default values...

Comment: Guice stil fails at start since it can't find a binding for Baz for example. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Strange - with `optional=true` it works for me and uses the default null value. Are you injecting Baz somewhere else, as well?

Answer (score 9):

The latest version of Guice recently added [`OptionalBinder`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/OptionalBinder.html) which works better than the `@Inject(optional=true)` method and also adds several advanced features.

See also the [thread where `OptionalBinder` was announced](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-guice/zvhQiZozcDU).

Comment: Worth noting this requires a lot more ceremony than using field injection with `@Inject(optional=true)`, and is more geared towards library authors.